# The widgets in Android Studio v 3.1.4 does not appear in Design Mode

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-constraintlayout, android-layout-editor

I am new to Android Studio and I was working on v3.1.4. When I was dragging any of the widgets and put it in the design, it does not appear. It gives me an error message that the widget is not constrained and it will jump to (0,0) point unless you add a constraint to it. When I use the magic wand the error disappeared but the problem still exist and the widget does not appear.

[image]

The code:

```
package com.example.amr.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should edit your question to include the text of your error message.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions about the very same issue that you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Step1: Open `SDK Manager` then install the latest SDK from that.

Step2: Shift to `SDK Tools` section in `SDK Manager` then install everything except NDK.

Step3: Restart Android Studio.

Finally, Problem Solved. (See the image below for reference)

Hopefully it will work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the Attributes panel collapsed on the left, inside that can put costraints on the current selected widget.
You'll see a square with four plus signs around to add costraints.

[image]